# aws beanstalk php worker scaling

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, worker-process

I have a very lightweight PHP script running in my worker environment. CPU utilization is next to nothing. To get my SQS queue under control I have to keep manually launching new workers to bring the number down. How can I get my workers to autoscale when the request count and CPU utilization are low?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html

Comment: I've learned that to scale an app like mine, I need to create a custom CloudWatch metric alarm and scaling rule to scale when the queue gets over a certain size. One peculiar note is that new instances seem to process much faster than older instances. All instances are healthy so I'm not sure where the slowdown is occurring.